# Base abbreviations other than ACTGU in sequence file

Tags: rna-seq

**Short question:**
where can I find what `F` and `J` and `<` and `-` and `7` mean in a Sequence file?

**Longer version:**
I was looking at this sequence file I got from NCBI (it's an sra file? if that is the correct terminology) and I used the `sratoolkit` to print out a few `spot`s

looking at them I expected to see ACGU (this was meant to be an RNA sequence), but what I see are like

> AAFFFJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJF<JJ77AJJJJ-JJJJJFF7FA--F7FAJJ7<AJ-FJA<J<JJFA<<77F-JJJJJJF<JF<7-FF-A-----A-77JJ7FJJF-FFFAJ<<-FJJFAJAFFAFFFFF<7A7JFJJ7AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJAA<JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJAAFFJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJ-FJF

Where can I find a reference to help me "understand" this?
I mean I assume `-` means missed or unknown? or is it meant to be already aligned and these are deletions?

I appreciate any pointer to get started. as you must have observed I am a total noob.

I got the file from: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/SRX8156420[accn]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/SRX8156420%5Baccn%5D)

Then I did a

```
 ./fastq-dump -X 5 -Z ERR4557575
```

Follow-up question:

- Where do you look for the quality scores ranges and such, I guess as @winnie2k suggested I should convert this to FASTQ and make my life easier, but still wanted to understand the file better.

Comment: Regarding the follow-up question: SRA files are a red herring. Nobody I know cares about the SRA file format ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually convert SRA files to FASTQ before doing any further processing, but the tooling for converting SRA files is cumbersome.

To simplify things, I recommend you download the FASTQ file directly. The ENA currently has a nicer interface for doing these things. Here is a link to download the FASTQ files for the SRA sequencing run associated with the SRA experiment you are describing: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/view/SRR11588968

A description of the FASTQ format can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format